# Agregar columna dependiendo del nombre del archivo con pandas

Tags: pandas

Por favor me ayuda con la siguiente duda

Quiero unir varios archivos csv y agregar una columna que indique a que archivo pertenece cada registro he intentado con este código pero me marca error

Aquí importo todos los archivos a unir

```
import os, re, pandas as pd
archivos=[x for x in os.listdir() if re.search('20240209*',x)]
>>> archivos

['T1120037204001_20240209.csv',
 'T1120037204002_20240210.csv',
 'T1120037204003_20240211.csv']
 

DataFrame()
df.to_csv('prueba.csv', index=False)
for i in archivos:
    archivo = pd.read_csv(i)
    df=pd.concat([archivo,df])
```

Aquí  le digo que todo lo que diga “20240209” agregue una columna con el dato “09”

```
df = {'20240209':'09', '20240210':'10','20240211':'11'}


for keyword, prueba in df.items():
    if keyword.lower() in df.lower():
        break
    else:
        [archivos]= 'otros'
```

Comment: He editado tu código pero sigue habiendo cosas que están mal formateadas porque no sabía a que hacía referencia. Dataframe(), archivos y df. Aparte en la línea <[archivos]='otros'>, como vas a igualar una lista a un string?? Aparte, también debes indicar cual es el error que te da